# How to add character limit to ExtJS HTML editor

Tags: html, oracle, extjs

I have an HTML editor in ExtJS.

I want to limit user to add characters in it.

I will be storing this value in database in HTML form like-

```
<font color="FF6600" face="verdana"><i>​This is the HTML text</i></font><br>
```

My question is, (1) what should be the limit of characters if data type of column is VARCHAR2(2000)

(2) Which property should I use to limit the characters. I tried using  `maxLength: 250` but it is not working. It allows user to add more than 250 characters.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlEditor does not contain a property called maxLength, only textfields do, you'd have to implement this yourself.

You could use the change event for something like this.

```
listeners: {
    change: function(editor, newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue.length > editor.maxLength) {
            editor.setValue(oldValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can go check the source of the `Ext.form.field.Text` how they do it for textfields.